# CSS Background Color for div

Tags: css, background, background-color

I have an input field and several images nested within one div. On the div I have set a background color but the issue is that the background color is only showing up for the first nested element which is the input field and no background color where the images fall under it.

You can view it here: http://kbanda2.rochestercs.org/abc/home.html , username&password=k

Earlier I had a fixed height for the div which solved the issue but I don't want to have a fixed height incase more elements are added after.

You can view the page source if needed or inspect element.

Actual Code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput2" name="q" size="30" maxlength="120" value="Enter cuisine type" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="pop()" class="tfbutton2" />
    <br/>
    <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
        <!--restaurants will be appended into here through a script-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.da-thumbs li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    left:10px;
}
.da-thumbs li a, .da-thumbs li a img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color:white;
    padding:5;
}
.da-thumbs li a {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    //top: 0px;
    bottom: -100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.da-thumbs li a:hover div {
    bottom: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    max-width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 2%;
    background:#dde0e1;
}
```

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce your issue *in the question itself*

Comment: @ZachSaucier I have edited it to reflect my code

Comment: U want to apply background color to wrapper? Please try z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the floating elements in the list.
All the **li** in **ul** are having float.

The solution is add class **clearfix** on the wrapper div.
And add the below css too.

**CSS**

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="wrapper">
       <input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput2" name="q" size="30" maxlength="120" value="Enter cuisine type"><input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="pop()" class="tfbutton2">
    <br>
    <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
     </ul>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

In css

```
.clearfix
{
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow: hidden; for wrapper

```
#wrapper{
max-width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 2%;
background: #dde0e1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```